# In angular-google-maps, how to show infoWindow via a mouseover event on marker?

Tags: google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am working on a project with angular-google-maps. 
I wanted to add a mouseover event to markers, so I followed the tutorial in the angular-google-maps example folders.
However, I can't get it work.
Here is the Plunker link.
http://plnkr.co/edit/bsqILbPPBJnZwyzeumn8?p=preview

```
        <ui-gmap-windows show="show">
            <div ng-non-bindable>{{text}}</div>
        </ui-gmap-windows>
```

$scope.markersEvents = {
            mouseover: function (gMarker, eventName, model) {

```
                model.show = true;

                $scope.$apply();

            }
```

};

Answer (score 0):

use this show="'show'" instead of show="show", worked for me

Comment: This fixed it for me. The reason being is that ui-gmap-windows directive is using a '=' scope for show rather than '@' meaning "show" uses a variable of show. Another fix for this would be making `$scope.show = "show";`